# In what format does Excel save CSV file when it prompts(explained in body)

Tags: excel, csv

I performed a write operation from a java program to create a csv file which has fields like:

"123", "Mainland", "hello,boy", " I like "war and peace" ",.....

Now when I was trying to upload this file into a postgres (9.1) database using 
COPY tablea from 'filename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV; 
I got an error saying: extra data after last expected column.

I believe it's because of the ' " ' inside the value in the 4th column that I'm getting this error.

I also found out that by just opening the file in excel and saving it again, selecting yes for the prompt :"filename.csv may contain features that are not compatible with csv, do you want to keep this format" does all the necessary changes.

Like after clicking yes if i perform a read in java from the same file(newly formatted by excel), the columns look like :

123, Mainland, "hello, boy", " I like ""war and peace"" "

This new file (after the save) also uploads successfully. I tried this on a small file. But my original file has 2.5 Million records(>2.5gb) and excel just cannot open it. Do you have any idea on how excel saves it? So that I could apply the change manually to my file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you see how Excel changed all the single " inside the field to "" (doeble ")?  I think that's the answer.  Excel also removed the " from around fields that do not contain spaces, commas or embedded " but I don't think that makes a difference.  So try to replace all " that are not on field boundaries with "" and see if that works.

If there are no "," sequences embedded inside any field then you could simply replace all " with "" and then replace all "","" with "," but of course that doesn't work if there are any "," sequences inside a field.  The question is, if there were any "," embedded inside a field how would anyone know if it was a field delimiter or not?